# 2 billion distinct values per column limitation

Tags: ssas, sql-server-2012

According to [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522628.aspx), columns in SSAS tabular models are limited to 2 billion DISTINCT values.  Does this apply across partitions?

For example, say I have a fact table with 4 billion records and a PK column containing values from 1 to 4,000,000,000.  Based on the link above, I'm assuming processing would fail once it hit the limit.  So could I partition the table and have the 2billion distinct limit apply at the partition level?

Also, does this limit apply to DirectQuery partitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, once you go beyond 2B distinct values, processing would fail.  A way to work around this issue would be to create two separate tables and then use DAX to merge them together.